# How can I pass a string variable to script.m which I run with math -script script.m?

Tags: scripting

I am not a very experienced programer, so this question might be trivial.
I have a program which should run multiple mathematica scripts. There I need to pass some string variable, say "A" to some script, say script.m, and in particular replace every occurence of some string "X" with the variable "A". Say I have the script

```
expr = 3;
    
Export["Xout.m",expr];
```

Then, when I run script.m from the command line, I want to pass to it a string expression for X, say A, such that it outputs the file Aout.m, which contains the number 3. That means I want something like

```
math -script script.m X=A
```

which of course does not work.
Is this possible to do? Or should I do this in some other way?

Comment: check $ScriptCommandLine. It will contain a list with the script name and all command line arguments as a list of strings. Any parsing of those strings you would have to do yourself, though. AFAIK there is no builtin or standard package to handle command line arguments as exist for other languages...

Comment: @AlbertRetey Thanks. This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: If you found a solution that works for you the site welcomes self-answering. If no other answers are given, you can even accept it. That might help others with the same question and keep the number of un-answered questions low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ScriptCommandLine does exactly this. In my case I used the Wolframscript and

```
./script.wls A
```

Then the variable A is stored as $ScriptCommandLine[[2]] inside the script. My code should look like

```
expr = 3;
    
Export[$ScriptCommandLine[[2]] <> "out.m",expr];
```